# Palindrome function- expected different outputs - javascript

Tags: javascript, string, output, reverse, palindrome

Challenge received: String Challenge
Have the function stringchallenge str take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is possible to create a palindromic string or minimum length 3 characters by removing 1 or 2 characters. For example: if str is 'abjchba' then you can remove the characters jc to produce abba which is a palindrome. For this example your program should return the Two characters that were removed with no delimiter and in the order they appear in the string. so jc. If 1 or 2 characters cannot be remove to produce a palindrome, then return the string not possible.
If the input string is already a palindrome, your program should return the string palindrome. Your program should always remove the characters that appear earlier in the string. In the
example above, you can also remove ch to form a palindrome but jc appears first, so the correct answer is jc. The input will only contain lowercase alphabetic characters. Your program should always attempt to create the longest palindromic substring by removing 1 or 2 characters see
second sample test case as an example. The 2 characters you remove do not have to be adjacent in the string.

My question is, what should I do to get the function to give the expected output when the substring has been removed to create the palindrome? Can someone help me please???

```
function StringChallenge(str) {
  if(str === str.split("").reverse().join("")) {return str;};
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let items = str[i];
    for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
      items += str[j];
      if (items === items.split("").reverse().join("")) {
        if ( result.length < items.length) {result = items;}
      }
    }
  }  
  return result.length < 3 ? "not possible" : result ;
}
console.log(StringChallenge("kjjjhjjj")); // output expected "k" - output received "jjjhjjj"
console.log(StringChallenge("ana")); // output expected "ana" - ok
console.log(StringChallenge("mmop")); // output expected "not possible" - ok
```

Comment: I would suggest first figuring out which functions to employ and your testing conditions. create multiple functions to test against. write some psudo-code and really expand on your current code first ( don't use chaining ). get that working and then do a re-factor to add some shortcuts with chaining.  first step would be filter / condition data: ensure that min length is there, that everything is lower case. create a test function to see if a string is a palindrome, then start to modify the string and pass that to your test function.  palindrome test function should return bool

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer:
I think this code will work on all test cases.

```js
function StringChallenge(str) {
  const RESULT_PALINDROME = "palindrome";
  const RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE = "not possible";

  function reverseString(string) {
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
  }

  function isPalindrome(string) {
    return string === reverseString(string);
  }

  function createPalindrome(inputStr, reverseOrder) {
    let str = reverseOrder ? reverseString(inputStr) : inputStr;
    let result = '';
    let temp = str;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] !== str[str.length - 1 - i]) {
        if (removeCharAndCheck()) return result;
      }
    }
    return RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE;

    function removeCharAndCheck() {
      result += temp[0];
      temp = temp.substring(1);
      return isPalindrome(temp) && temp.length > 2;
    }
  }

  // If the input string is already a palindrome
  if (isPalindrome(str)) return RESULT_PALINDROME;

  const fromFirst = createPalindrome(str, false);
  const fromLast = createPalindrome(str, true);

  if (fromFirst !== RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE && fromLast !== RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE) {
    if (fromFirst.length > 2 || fromLast.length > 2) return RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE;
    return fromFirst.length > fromLast.length ? fromLast : fromFirst;
  }

  if (fromFirst !== fromLast && fromFirst === RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE) {
    return fromLast.length > 2 ? RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE : fromLast;
  }

  if (fromLast !== fromFirst && fromLast === RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE) {
    return fromFirst.length > 2 ? RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE : fromFirst;
  }

  return RESULT_NOT_POSSIBLE;
}

console.log(StringChallenge("kjjjhjjj"));
console.log(StringChallenge("ana"));
console.log(StringChallenge("mmop"));
```